# Only fetch Results from Api when iterated

Tags: c#, ienumerable, api-design

I have an Api that fetches results in pages and sends them back to the client. How do i minimise the number of page fetches from the api before knowing how my items the client will actually iterate over. IE lets say a client only takes 5 Foo items. My api wil currently fetch all pages even tho only 5 items is used by the client. Is there any onther way than passing in the number of items to be fetched?

```
var actualItems = _pagedApiCollection.GetItems<Foo>().Take(5).ToList();
```

Api Call

```
 public IEnumerable<Foo> GetItems<Foo>()
 {
    public List<object> allElements = new List<object>();

       do
        {
            currentpage =  _pagedApi.GetNextPage(reqid);


            allElements.AddRange(currentpage.Items); 

        } while (currentpage.HasNextPage);

   IEnumerable<Foo> myNewEnumerable = allElements.Cast<Foo>();
   myNewEnumerable; 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could turn this into a proper enumerable method by yielding the results one by one.

```
public IEnumerable<Foo> GetItems<Foo>() {
    Page currentPage;
    do
    {
        currentPage =  _pagedApi.GetNextPage(reqid);

        foreach (var item in currentPage)
            yield return (Foo)item;

    } while (currentpage.HasNextPage);
}
```

You'll still need to fetch one page at a time so if you ask for 6 and but the page size of `_pagedApi` is 5 you will fetch 2 pages instead of everyone. This overhead is probably a lot smaller then what it would be to fetch each record one by one instead of by pages.

This is the strength of the IEnumerable interface, it creates a state machine in the background that keeps track of the current state of your loop (you can search for it here on SO or MSDN if you want a thorough explanation).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Slight issue is now item is of type object, how would i convert it to Type Foo. Previously List had a Cast method how would i do that for a single Object?

Comment: Thanks man this is the answer i was looking for I cant upvote yet since i dont have enough reputation

Comment: I guess you solved the cast then, I'll update the answer with it anyway. Even if you can't upvote you should be able to "accept" the answer via the checkmark under the voting arrows.

Comment: Thanks again bud your anwer was correct!! i have accepted